# How can I prevent inserting duplicate data into a SQL Server table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a series of data that need to be written into SQL, what should I do to check the data in SQL to prevent same data inserted into table?

Example data to be inserted:

```
David  
James  
John
```

If the 4th data is `John` again, I want the system to skip the duplicate record (John).

So far I have:

```
SqlConnection myCnn = new SqlConnection(cnn);
String _state = "Insert into CamNo1(platename, date, camID, path, filename) OUTPUT INSERTED.platename values(@msg, getdate(), @camID, @path, @filename)";
SqlCommand _Query = new SqlCommand(_state, myCnn);

_Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@msg", msg);
_Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@camID", camID);
_Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", imageFile);
_Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", name);

try
{
   myCnn.Open();
   string checkname = (string)_Query.ExecuteScalar();
   myCnn.Close();

   getcheckname = checkname;
   Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

i got the string value checkname that is last inserted, what should i do check the data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you can prevent a duplicate from ever occurring in the table by using a unique index or constraint.  An index/constraint can work *in concert* with the suggestions below.  If you *only* use a unique index and not one of the below solutions, inserting a duplicate record will throw an error and you will need to handle that on the other end.

Additionally, I would probably insert the data via a stored procedure that checks to see if the row already exists.  To do that, you can use either a **MERGE** statement, as shown in this pseudo code:

```
create procedure MyProcedure
(
    @Name nvarchar(100),
    ...
)
as

merge MyTable
using
(
    select @Name,...
) as source (Name, ...)
on MyTable.Name = source.Name
when not matched then
    insert (Name,...) values (source.Name,...)
when matched then
    update set Name = @Name,...
```

or, you could check for the records existence and insert or update manually:

```
create procedure MyProcedure
(
    @Name nvarchar(100),
    ...
)
as

    if not exists (select * from MyTable where Name = @Name)
    begin
        insert into MyTable (Name,...) values (@Name,...)
    end
    else
    begin
            update MyTable
            set ...
            where Name = @Name
    end
```

Comment: I agree that you should not use the constraint/index alone to deal with duplicate data, but it is nice to know you'll never have to sanitize data since you have that constraint in place.  I think you might be interested to look at the `MERGE` function that SQL Server 2008 added, it combines the syntax for your option of `If Exists Update Else Insert` and I believe they've made it more efficient. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

Comment: Yep, definitely know and use the MERGE statement.  May modify my answer to include an example.

Comment: Thanks for giving such detail answer, i am trying now :)

Comment: @BertEvans how should i run this statement? should i save in .sql file then run at c# or there is another way?

Comment: @Xuan: You will want to create the procedure on the database side, and then call it from your c# code.

Comment: @Xuan: I'm not sure you're going down the right path here.  You create the stored procedure using a database client tool, like SSMS.  Once you have the procedure created in the database, all you need to do is modify the C# code you posted in your question slightly to call the stored procedure from your C# code.

Comment: @BertEvans i got an error that 

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'procedure'.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5370/discussion-between-bert-evans-and-xuan)

Answer (score 6):

If you do not want duplicate data, you should consider enforcing that at the DB level with a [UNIQUE CONSTRAINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx) or a [UNIQUE INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx)

SQL Server 2008 also has a [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement you could use to check for matched records.  This could be helpful if you want to update an existing record.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to *prevent* duplicate data from being inserted, you could use a [unique index or unique constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224827%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) on those fields.

If you want to just run a hard insert statement, but have it do nothing if a value exists, something like this should work.  I tested this on a local database I have:

```
declare @subject as varchar(100);
set @subject = 'hello'

insert into Subjects ([name]) 
select @subject 
where not exists (select 1 from Subjects where [name] = @Subject)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This Easy way

```
  { 
        DataSet ds = New DataSet();
SqlConnection myCnn = New SqlConnection(cnn);
myCnn.Open();
                    SqlCommand _Query = New SqlCommand("Select *FROM CamNo1 where platename='" + Console.ReadLine + "' ", myCnn);
                  SqlDataAdapter  sda = New SqlDataAdapter(_Query);
                    sda.Fill(ds);

                    Int i = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                    If (i > 0) Then
                                {
                        MessageBox.Show("platename" + Console.WriteLine + "Already Exists ");
                        ds.Clear();
                    }
                    Else
                    {
                        SqlConnection myCnn = New SqlConnection(cnn);
String _state = "Insert into CamNo1(platename, date, camID, path, filename) OUTPUT INSERTED.platename values(@msg, getdate(), @camID, @path, @filename)";
SqlCommand _Query = New SqlCommand(_state, myCnn);

_Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@msg", msg);
_Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@camID", camID);
_Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", i`enter code here`mageFile`);
_Query.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filename", Name);

Try
{
   myCnn.Open();
   String checkname = (String)_Query.ExecuteScalar();
   myCnn.Close();

   getcheckname = checkname;
   Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
Catch (Exception)
{
}
                    }

  }
```