# SQL Server allow duplicates in any column, but not all columns

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I've searched through numerous threads to try to find an answer to this but any answer I've found suggests using a unique constraint on a single column, or multiple columns.

My problem is, I'm writing an application in C# with a SQL Server back end. One of the features is to allow a user to import a `.CSV` file into the database after a little bit of pre-processing. I need to find the quickest method to prevent the user from importing the same data more than once. The data will look something like

```
ID   -- will be auto-generated in SQL Server (PK)
Date Time(datetime)
Machine(nchar)
...
...
...
Name(nchar)
Age(int)
```

I want to allow any number of the columns to be duplicate values, a long as the entire record is not.

I was thinking of creating another column in the database, obtained by hashing all of the columns together and making it unique but want sure if that was the most efficient method, or if the resulting hash would be guaranteed unique. The CSV files will only be around 60 MB, but there will be tens of thousands of them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Insert the file in a temp table and use SQL Merge or insert where not exists statement from there on?

Comment: Are you able to insert into a temp table? If not can you use something like OPENDATASOURCE to query the data out of the CSV?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276336/how-can-i-prevent-inserting-duplicate-data-into-a-sql-server-table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to resolve this by creating a unique constraint which includes all the columns.

```
create table #a (col1 varchar(10), col2 varchar(10))

ALTER TABLE #a 
    ADD CONSTRAINT UQ UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
        (col1, col2)

-- Works, duplicate entries in columns
insert into #a (col1, col2)
    values   ('a', 'b')
            ,('a', 'c')
            ,('b', 'c')


-- Fails, full duplicate record:
insert into #a (col1, col2)
    values   ('a1', 'b1')
            ,('a1', 'b1')
```

Comment: Thanks, simple but effective. I don't know why I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

The code below can work to ensure that you don't duplicate the [Date Time], Machine, [Name] and Age columns when you insert the data.

It's important to ensure that at the time of running the code, each row of the incoming dataset has a unique ID on it. This code just fails to shift any rows where the ID gets selected because all four other values are already duplicated in the destination table.

```
INSERT INTO MAIN_TABLE ([Date Time],Machine,[Name],Age)
SELECT [Date Time],Machine,[Name],Age
FROM IMPORT_TABLE WHERE ID NOT IN
(
SELECT I.ID FROM IMPORT_TABLE I INNER JOIN MAIN_TABLE M 
ON I.[Date Time]=M.[Date Time] 
AND I.Machine=M.Machine 
AND I.[Name]=M.[Name] 
AND I.Age=M.Age
)
```